# CoreData getting objects based on a distinct property

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I've had a problem for a while and I have hacked together a solution but I am revisiting it in the hopes of finding a real solution.  Unfortunately that is not happening.  In Core Data I've got a bunch of RSS articles.  The user can subscribe to individual channels within a single feed.  The problem is that some feed providers post the exact same article in multiple channels of the same feed.  So the user ends up getting 2+ versions of the same article.  I want to keep all articles in case the user unsubscribes from a channel that contains one copy but stays subscribed to another channel with a duplicate, but I only want to show a single article in the list of available articles.

To identify duplicates, I create a hash value of the article text content and store it as a property on the Article entity in Core Data (text_hash).  My original thinking was that I would be able to craft a fetch request that could get the articles based on a unique match on this property, something like an SQL query.  That turns out not to be the case (I was just learning Core Data at the time).

So to hack up a solution, I fetch all the articles, I make an empty set, i enumerate the fetch results, checking if the hash is in the set.  If it is, I ignore it, if it isn't, i add it to the set and I add the article id to an array.  When I'm finished, I create a predicate based on the article ids and do another fetch.

This seems really wasteful and clumsy, not only am i fetching twice and enumerating the results, since the final predicate is based on the individual article ids, I have to re-run it every time I add a new article.

It works for now but I am going to work on a new version of this app and I would like to make this better if at all possible.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any attribute in your data that is the same for the duplicates? Let's say you have the Article.name, is that the same for all duplicates?

Comment: they are considered the same if the text_hash is identical, so yes, I have a property, Article.text_hash, and that is what I use to test for duplicates

Comment: So if you have that you could just fetch one object with that hash. But you probably wants to get rid of the other stuff?

Comment: what I want to do is fetch all articles that have the same channel_id but having only one version of every article that has duplicates.  The problem is that there's no way to craft a predicate that functions like SQL.  In SQL i would just do something like 'select * from article where channel_id = 5 group by text_hash' and I would get exactly what I want.

Comment: You could probably use NSCompoundPredicate.

Comment: how?  as far as I know, there's no nspredicate comparison operator that acts like SQL GROUP BY or finds objects based on a distinct value of a property?

Comment: I guess you could put them in a NSArray (not a set), implement a sortByHash method, and then just read your array with a loop, applying if (myCurrentElement.hash == myPreviousElement.hash) continue;

Comment: Your issue is not clear, a simple predicate of this format: @"text_hash = %@" would give you all articles matching your hash. also , you can GROUP BY by setting the `propertiesToGroupBy:@[<props>]` on your fetch request

Comment: ok, I guess I didn't specify that I am trying to use this in a NSFetchedResultsController to auto-populate a table view.  I don't care about fetching on the hash, what I want to do is get all articles but with no duplicates. Example, i have a1, a2, a3, a2.text_hash = a3.text_hash.  I want to get a1 and a2 but not a3 because it is identical to a2.  I was just reading about propertiesToGroupBy but the problem is I would have to go back and switch from using Article entities to dictionaries.  If that's what it takes I'll just stick with my current solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`propertiesToGroupBy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/propertiesToGroupBy) like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Article"];
fr.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"text_hash"];
fr.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
NSArray *articles = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];
```

Comment: The switch to an `NSDictionaryResultType` is the key here; it adds tons of flexibility to `NSFetchRequest`, including `havingPredicate:' and specifying custom expressions. Matt Connolly has an example of counting and grouping that you should take a look at if you're new to `NSDictionaryResultType`'s power: http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/

Comment: @JCS007: Actually I was searching around after asking this question and I came across propertiesToGroupBy.  But I have to switch to using dictionaries instead of Article entities. I have several table views and lot of methods that use Article entities and I don't have time to re-write all my methods to accommodate that change for this version.  I wish I had known about that when I started...I guess if this is the only way I will have to live with what I have for now.  Thanks for your response, I will remember this in the future!

Comment: @HalMueller: thanks for the link!  this will make for some good reading tonight...

Comment: Glad this helped! Perhaps instead of re-writing all those methods, you can have a de-duping method that runs at set times so as to weed out the duplicates. Just a thought. :)

Comment: actually, now that you mention it, I need to keep the duplicates around in case the user unsubscribes from one channel but not another (that might contain a duplicate), but I COULD flag duplicates and use that in a fetch predicate, then if I remove an article that has a duplicate, remove the flag...I wouldn't even have to use group by...I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: getting this error : `SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x60> , SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions ((<NSAttributeDescription: 0x60>), name id, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity ContactModel, renamingIdentifier id, validation predicates (), warnings (), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preserveValueOnDeletionInPersistentHistory NO is not in the GROUP BY) with userInfo of (null)`

Comment: @MehulThakkar Check the list of properties in the fetch request. Looks like you're using invalid ones.